# Jquery animate em

Tags: jquery

I come across a strange thing
i've made this code which extends the footer on an icon click and then when it's clicked again it goes back to start point which is 12em, but when i click the icon again it animates the height to 12px.
If i delete the .animate and use .css theres no problem
Can you guys please take a look and see what i've done wrong

```
$('.mail').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
        var height = $(window).height() - $('header').outerHeight();
        $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open').children('i').attr('data-icon', 'h');
        //$(this).addClass('open').removeClass('closed').children('i').addClass('icon-remove-sign').removeClass('icon-envelope-alt');
        $('footer').animate({
            height: height
        },500);
        $('#contact').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
    } 
    else if($(this).hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed').children('i').attr('data-icon', 'd');

        $('#contact').fadeOut(300);
        $('footer').animate({
            height: '12em',
        },500);

    }              

});
```

Thanks

Comment: can you add your html as well?

Answer (score 1):

You have a conflict in the var name:

```
var height = $(window).height() - $('header').outerHeight();
      ^--- Change this to be hght for example
```

then use it like this:

```
$('footer').animate({
            height: hght
...
...
```

Alternatively you can also do:

```
$('footer').animate({
            'height': height
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers i figured out at it dont work when i use the php include to include the header but why is that?

Comment: @MyRevenge could be a timing issue, are you wrapping the above code in a `document ready function`?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are expecting the the `.mail` division to have more than two `class states`, you do not need to use the `else if`. You can , but you could do this to simplify code:

```
$(function() {
$('.mail').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('closed')) {
        var hght = $(window).height() - $('header').outerHeight();
        $(this).removeClass('closed').addClass('open').children('i').attr('data-icon', 'h');
        $('footer').animate({
            height: hght
        },500);
        $('#contact').delay(400).fadeIn(300);
        return;
        } 
   $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('closed').children('i').attr('data-icon', 'd');
   $('#contact').fadeOut(300);
   $('footer').animate({
        height: '12em',
     },500);
    });
});
```

Or use `else` instead